# A single variable calculus book after doing Apostol's vol 1

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I have finished studying Calculus vol 1 by Tom M Apostol. Can you tell me a more advanced single variable calculus book so that I can study it?. Should I go for calculus on manifolds?

Note:I haven't studied multi-variable calculus.

Answer (score 1):

You'll *definitely* want to do some - actually lots of - multivariable calculus before heading to calculus on manifolds.  For that, I would recommend Apostol or Stewart - both have lots of problems with solutions (the best way to learn, in my opinion, is doing problems and checking your solution).  If you're interested in deeper single variable calculus theory, you should also learn some mathematical analysis - for instance Apostol's "mathematical analysis" or Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis."

Good luck!